# Sitecore Licensing and Site Domains

Tags: license

I have a question about `Sitecore Licensing`.

I am aware that number of machines, Sitecore functionalities and number of concurrent users supported would affect licensing.

I was wondering whether number of domains that my site has, would that have any impact on `Sitecore Licensing`?

So if I have more domains, do I need to pay more for the license?

Comment: The answer would very much depend on which product you are licensing and what license model you have (perpetual, subscription) - the only way to get a definitive answer is to talk to your Sitecore rep.

Comment: Thanks Richard!

Answer (score 0):

For sitecore xm/xp on premise, roughly ,the `number` of public `Top domains` is one the affectomg factors. Other than that,`Site visits per month`, `Concurrent users`,`product envs` and `Non-production installations`,`Add-on modules` also impact on Sitecore Licensing.

- Site Visits Per Month: The amount of unique website sessions your site receives.
- Non-Production Environments: The amount of test and development environments your business needs.
- Concurrent Users: The amount of users you have in Sitecore when the users are concurrently using the platform.

While the `subdomain` is not the key factor which is unlimited.

As for other saas product with Sitecore, the `storage` and `bandwidth` will be the new key factors.

hope it helps and suggest you talk to a sales in Sitecore to get more info.